# How to set a DB Flag depending on previous row value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group the records in a SQL Server table with alternate 1 and 0 combination.

I am actually trying to get 1 when the previous row has the same date value and 0 if it is not so that i get the alternate.

I know I can do this using the `LAG` function in SQL Server 2012. Can someone help me with the easiest way in SQL Server 2008?

Here is what I am trying to do :

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE_ID, 
    CASE 
       WHEN LAG(MODIFIED_ON) OVER (ORDER BY MODIFIED_ON) = MODIFIED_ON 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
    END AS COMPAREDVALUE 
FROM TBL_A
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're describing, if you partition the records by your mod date, the first record in a given set of records will have `0` (because the previous partition has a different date), and the remainder will have `1`. So all you have to do is partition them by mod date, then flag the first one:

```
SELECT 
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    CASE
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY MODIFIED_ON ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID
        ) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [COMPAREDVALUE]
FROM TBL_A
```